# having problems with rails integration testing and session variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

using rails 3.1 here. i am having some problems with session variables in my integration test.

```
test "new registration" do

get "/user/sign_up?type=normal"
assert_response :success
assert_equal 'normal', session[:registration]
assert_template "user_registrations/new"


assert_difference('User.count', +1) do
  post "/user", :user => {:email => "kjsdfkjksjdf@sdfsdf.com", :user_name => "lara", :password => "dfdfdfdfdfdf", :password_confirmation => "dfdfdfdfdfdf"}
end
assert_response :redirect
assert_template "user_registrations/new"

@user = User.find_by_user_name('lara')
assert_equal 'lara', @user.user_name
@user.confirm!

end
```

all of the assertions pass so thats good, but from what i can tell, session[:registration] is not getting passed when post to "/user".

in my create action in the user_registration controller:

```
 if session[:registration] == "normal"
    @user.role = "normal"
    @user.status = "registering"
    @user.save
  else
    @user.role = "fan"
    @user.save
  end
```

So when the user is created, @user.role = "fan", when it should be @user.role = "normal".

I cant seem to get that session variable to pass when i post. from what i understand, in the "new registration" test, all the session variables remain active as long as the test has not ended. am i wrong to assume that that session variable should be posted? any suggestions?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing uses `open_session do |sess|` and then `sess.post` so you can probably do something similar